# Reading a text in two voices

Tags: text-to-speech

Is there a way to read aloud a text in two voices automatically?

For example, male voice for questions and female voice for answers.
Or, even paragraphs with one accent and odd paragraphs with a different accent.

Preferably in French.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not find a free and easy solution. Free readers seem to offer only single voice reading.

There are some paid solutions (with free trials).

- murf.ai mobile and web-app with a convenient editor and script. For French, 2 male and 2 female free voices. Canadian French voices are only available for a fee. I did not figure out how to change voices to paragraphs automatically, had to assign voices manually via GUI. The free trial (no credit card) allows one produce up to 10 min of dialogues.
- tableread PRO app - several days trial, need PDF script, formatted professionally (such as on simplyscript.com) and some voice assistant already installed on the device. The free version of the app seems single voice.

Also, I imagine there is a way to use a voiced GPT version to get help here. There could be a way to generate voices for each personage separately and then mix everything in one file.

There is plenty of free reading tool but in a single voice.